# Do I need to double the voltage with double the motors?

Tags: voltage, current, dc, dc-motor

I am totally new to electronics.

Let's say I am building a DC circuit with a motor using 6V taking 1.28A.
Now, if I build a circuit that uses two of these motors, will I power the circuit with 6V and the circuit will use 2.56A or will I need to power it with 12V and the motors will use 2.56A combined or what?

Comment: You have to specify if the motors are connected in series or in parallel, since the implications are different in each case. You should also state what your DC power source is rated for.

Answer (score 7):

If the motors are in parallel (i.e. 6 V to both of them), you still need 6 V but 2.56 A. If they are in series (i.e. voltage goes to one, its other lead goes to voltage pin of the other one), then you need 12 V, but sill only 1.28 A.

Answer (score 7):

Generally it is best to run the motors in parallel and use more current at the same 6V.  You don't mention the type of DC motor but if you stack them across 12V you might get unexpected speed control issues.